# Can't connect to libcluster when starting mix release with `eval`

Tags: elixir

Is there a difference between `start` and `eval` with a mix release if you call `Application.ensure_all_started(:app)` in your `eval` code? For some reason I'm having an issue connecting to libcluster nodes when starting the app with `eval`.

I get this error `unable to connect to :\"app@10.32.0.60\": not part of network`

It connects fine when using `start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation on [`mix release`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html?#module-one-off-commands-eval-and-rpc)

> The `eval` command starts its own instance of the VM but without starting any of the applications in the release **and without starting distribution**.

The emphasis is mine.

`:"app@10.32.0.60"` is the long name requiring a distributed erlang to be started.

Fancy descriptive “not part of network” error message tried to tell you exactly this. In general, you might restart your node in distributed mode with [`Node.start/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#start/3) and then restart your application, but I’d avoid this and use `start` which in this case seems what you actually need.

Comment: I need to run it as `eval` due to running a script as a k8s cronjob and I don't want to complicate it by polling for when the node is ready when using `start`

Comment: Ah, k8s :) This piece of code from my library managing cluster transparently might shed a light on what are you likely after: https://github.com/am-kantox/cloister/blob/master/lib/cloister/monitor.ex#L294-L302

Comment: I tried the `Node.start` but got this error `Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: econnrefused`. Do you know what that might mean?

Comment: nevermind, I got it to work by starting epmd, thanks!